# Standard PHP error function with __LINE__ __FILE__etc?

Tags: php, error-handling

so, instead of lots of instances of

```
if (odbc_exec($sql))
{
}
else
{
  myErrorHandlingFunction();
}
```

I wrap that in a function

```
function myOdbxExec($sql)
{
  if (odbc_exec($sql))
  {
  }
  else
  {
    myErrorHandlingFunction();
  }
}
```

**BUT** I would like `myErrorHandlingFunction()` to report things like  `__LINE__` `__FILE__` etc

Which looks like I have to pass thoses infos to every call of helper functions, e.g. `myOdbxExec($sql, __FILE__, __LINE__)` which makes my code look messy.

```
function myErrorHandlingFunction($errorTExt, $fiel, $line)
{
  // error reporting code goes here
}


function myOdbxExec($sql, $file, $line)
{
  if (odbc_exec($sql))
  {
  }
  else
  {
    myErrorHandlingFunction();
  }
}

$sql = 'select * from ... blah, blah, blah...';
myOdbxExec($sql, __FILE__, __LINE__);   // <==== this is *ugly*
```

In C I would hide it all behind a #define, e.g. `#define MY_OFBC_EXEC(sql) myOdbxExec(sql, __FILE__, __LINE__)`

1) (how) can I do that in PHP
2) what else is worth outoputting? e.g. `error_get_last()`? but that has no meaning if odbc_exec() fails ...

To rephrase the question - what's the generic approach to PHP error handling? (especially when `set_error_handler()` doesn't really apply?

---

Edit: just to be clear - I do want to handle exceptions, programming errors, etc, but, as my example shows, I also want to handle soemthings the teh PHP interpreter might noit consider to be an error, like `odbc_exec()` returning false().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both the above answers mentioning debug_backtrace are answering your _______LINE_____ / _______FILE___ question with the debug_backtrace() function.  I've wanted this answer too in the past, so have put together a quick function to handle it.

```
function myErrorHandlingFunction($message, $type=E_USER_NOTICE) {
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    foreach($backtrace as $entry) {
        if ($entry['function'] == __FUNCTION__) {
            trigger_error($entry['file'] . '#' . $entry['line'] . ' ' . $message, $type);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can then call, for instance, `myErrorHandlingFunction('my error message');`

or `myErrorHandlingFunction('my fatal error message', E_USER_ERROR);`

or `try { ... } catch (Exception $e) { myErrorHandlingFunction($e->getMessage()); }`

Comment: +1 That looks very good!! I'll give it a try and tell you how it goes. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

First off, you might want to consider using [exception handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

If for some reason, that doesn't appeal to you, you can use [debug_backtrace](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) inside your generic error handler to figure out where the handler was called from.

**EDIT** In response to OP's comment:

Exceptions don't have to come from PHP built-ins.  You can throw your own.  Since an ODBC error generally *is* an exceptional condition, just `throw` an exception when you detect one.  (And `catch` it at some higher level).

```
<?PHP
if (! odbc_exec($sql) ) 
    throw new DatabaseException('odbc_exec returned false, that bastard!');
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. I editted the question to add this "just to be clear - I do want to handle exceptions, programming errors, etc, but, as my example shows, I also want to handle soemthings the the PHP interpreter might not consider to be an error, like `odbc_exec()` returning false()."

Answer (score 1):

Use [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) to figure out where a function was called from in your error handler. Whether you invoke this error handler by manually calling it, by throwing and catching exceptions, PHPs `error_handler` or any other method is up to the application design and doesn't really differ that much from other languages.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I editted the question to add this "just to be clear - I do want to handle exceptions, programming errors, etc, but, as my example shows, I also want to handle soemthings the teh PHP interpreter might noit consider to be an error, like `odbc_exec()` returning false()."